# SVM: What is relationship between the number of features and the number of dimensions?

Tags: machine-learning, python, svm

I have implemented a support vector machine (SVM) in Python. I want to know the relationship between the number of features and the number of dimensions. My dataset contains 5 features, does it mean that my SVM classifier has 5 dimensions? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Excluding the target variable, if your dataset has $n$ columns (predictors, covariates etc.), then your SVM separates the space $\mathbb{R}^n$. So, Your SVM operates on $n$ dimensional data. The separating hyperplane is in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, i.e. $n-1$ dimensional by definition, and its equation can be generally written as $w^Tx+b$, where $w,x$ are $n$ dimensional, and $b$, bias, is $1$ dimensional (i.e. a scalar). So, the hyperplane equation has $n+1$ coefficients, including the bias term, which means your parameter space is $n+1$ dimensional.  I haven't heard a term like SVM dimension, but these are all the dimensionality concerns inside the classifier.